# Understanding Hadoop behavior with GZ files

Tags: hadoop

I have a small JSON file in two separate folders in my S3 bucket. I ran the same command with the same mapper on those two separately.

**NORMAL JSON**

```
$ hadoop jar /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file ./mapper.py -mapper ./mapper.py -input s3://mybucket/normaltest -output smalltest-output
14/08/28 08:33:53 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
packageJobJar: [./mapper.py, /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-unjar6225144044327095484/] [] /tmp/streamjob6947060448653690043.jar tmpDir=null
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of map tasks: null
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting default number of map tasks based on cluster size to : 160
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of reduce tasks: 0
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: add hadoop to shell userGroupsCache
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting group to hadoop
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
14/08/28 08:33:56 WARN lzo.LzoCodec: Could not find build properties file with revision hash
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev UNKNOWN]
14/08/28 08:33:56 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/08/28 08:33:56 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/08/28 08:33:58 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/28 08:33:58 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred]
14/08/28 08:33:58 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201408260907_0053
14/08/28 08:33:58 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/08/28 08:33:58 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.165.13.124:9001 -kill job_201408260907_0053
14/08/28 08:33:58 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://ip-10-165-13-124.ec2.internal:9100/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201408260907_0053
14/08/28 08:33:59 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:23 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 1%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 2%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 9%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:32 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 45%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:35 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 56%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:36 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 57%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:38 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 84%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:39 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 85%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:41 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 99%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:44 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:34:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
14/08/28 08:34:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job complete: job_201408260907_0053
14/08/28 08:34:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Output: smalltest-output
```

In `smalltest-output`, I get several small files containing a part of the processed JSON.

**GZIPed JSON**

```
$ hadoop jar /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 -file ./mapper.py -mapper ./mapper.py -input s3://weblablatency/gztest -output smalltest-output
14/08/28 08:39:45 WARN conf.Configuration: DEPRECATED: hadoop-site.xml found in the classpath. Usage of hadoop-site.xml is deprecated. Instead use core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to override properties of core-default.xml, mapred-default.xml and hdfs-default.xml respectively
packageJobJar: [./mapper.py, /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-unjar2539293594337011579/] [] /tmp/streamjob301144784484156113.jar tmpDir=null
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of map tasks: null
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting default number of map tasks based on cluster size to : 160
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of reduce tasks: 0
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: add hadoop to shell userGroupsCache
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting group to hadoop
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
14/08/28 08:39:48 WARN lzo.LzoCodec: Could not find build properties file with revision hash
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev UNKNOWN]
14/08/28 08:39:48 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/08/28 08:39:48 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/08/28 08:39:50 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/08/28 08:39:51 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred]
14/08/28 08:39:51 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201408260907_0055
14/08/28 08:39:51 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
14/08/28 08:39:51 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.165.13.124:9001 -kill job_201408260907_0055
14/08/28 08:39:51 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://ip-10-165-13-124.ec2.internal:9100/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201408260907_0055
14/08/28 08:39:52 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:40:20 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
14/08/28 08:40:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
14/08/28 08:40:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job complete: job_201408260907_0055
```

In smalltest-output I get a correctly parsed file, but as a single file.

Why this difference and what is happening? Is my job not being distributed properly in the `gz` case?

In my actual use case I need to process ~2000 gz files totalling to around 4GB uncompressed; every 4 hours. So I can't afford any performance issues because of compression.

Comment: Yes as Clement points out this has been talked about Bazillions of times. I want to add that comprehsion in general does not slow down jobs, in fact it can speed up jobs. This is because modern CPUs and libraries can decompress data faster than disks can be read - usually jobs bottleneck on disk io, not cpu.

Answer (score 1):

Gzip is not splittable. You will find bazillions of  articles and questions speaking about this issue so I won't go into details.

Your options are:

- Don't use Gzip (don't compress or use another splittable compression format)
- Use a hack to make GZip splittable, like https://github.com/nielsbasjes/splittablegzip. Each mapper will still have to read the file from the beginning so it's a trade-off. Read the documentation to learn more.

It depends on what you do, but for most processing 4GB of data is nothing. I would make sure that I really need an elephant like Hadoop for my use case. It is scalable but complex, painful to work and usually slow for small data sets.

Comment: So considering I supply Hadoop with 6000 files in my input dir, I can expect it to divide the load right in terms of entire files, if not file chunks, right?